Выделение строки с последующим дроблением на отдельные элементы массива
У меня есть задача, написать калькулятор на веб сайте. Возникла проблема, что я не могу раздробить строку на отдельные элементы для массива, чтобы дальше уже взаимодействовать с выражениями.
Вот как я получаю строку в массив:
<input id = "area" class="area" rows="2" cols="50" readonly ></input>

mas = [Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input'), v=> v.value)];

Но итог не тот что мне нужен. Так как вся строка помещается в один элемент этого массива, а не дробится. То есть массив выглядит так "mas = ["333-66+5"]".
А результат что я хочу получить должен выглядеть "mas = ["333","-","66","+","5"]". То есть строка должна полностью раздробиться.
Я пробовал это сделать через вот такой способ
mas.slice(mas.charAt(mas.indexOf("-" || "+")));


в примере у вас не строка, а массив. И привидете больше подробностей. Что за исходные данные. Как выглядит ваша "строка", какой результат ожидаете и что именно не получилось(желательно с примером кода)

@SwaD прошу прощения за недоразумение, исправил описание

Уберите [] вокруг Array.from и будет массив. Сейчас как я понимаю вы получили массив с 1 элементом где лежит массив из строк

@SwaD убрал [], но это не дало результата. Все также строка закидывается в один элемент массива

У вас все эти значения же в разных полях? Или вписано в одно поле? Я у себя посмотрел, скрипт прекрасно собирает данные в массив. Значение каждого инпута лежит в своем элементе.

попробуйте использовать 'split' 'let items = mas[0].split(/[+-/*]+/);', так как вы получите массив из кучи инпутов и они составят одну строку, по этому нужно указать что 'mas[0]' И SwaD правильно написал уберите []

@SwaD это все в одном поле, поэтому я и обратился с этой проблемой..

А... это одна строка... Что то мне подсказывает, что код тоже не ваш(по крайней мере, написан не осознанно без понимания, как он работает), который представлен в вопросе. Поясните, зачем вы хотите разбить строку? Сколько операторов там может быть? А что если есть буква?

Если у вас одно поле, почему используется querySelectorAll? Готовое решение под одну строку дал вам LureRed

@SwaD Да, помещение строки в массив нашел в интернете. Понимания что и как работает, с учетом моего опыта, конечно мало, поэтому еще многие вещи не приходят в голову сами. Но проблема решена с помощью  LureRed.
Разбиваю строку для более удобного взаимодействия затем с операциями в самописном калькуляторе, так как хочется сделать его многофункциональным и поэтому операторов может быть до бесконечности, а буквы я не допущу через доп проверку на валидность строки)

Если у вас не коммерческий проект, а для себя, можно использовать для единой строки new Function. Вот пример с калькулятором, а это просто пример более простой

@SwaD прошу прощения за глупый вопрос, но как мне отметить вопрос решенным(я просто еще зеленый на этом сайте, не бейте)? просто человек LureRed смог решить проблему(ваш вариант тоже неплох, но грамосток), но он ответил в комментариях и я не могу отметить это как решение..

Никак. Либо обратитесь к нему напрямую @LureRed - вот так и попросите оформить комментарий, как ответ. Если ответа не будет, вы можете самостоятельно опубликовать решение, это тоже допускается и даже приветствуется. Как пример

@LureRed я не хочу присваивать ваш ум себе, поэтому оформите свой вариант в ответ, он мне помог.

попробуйте использовать 'split'


mas = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input'), v=> v.value);// [] скобочки убираем
let items = mas[0].split(/[+-/*]+/);
<input id = "area" class="area" rows="2" cols="50" readonly ></input>



так как вы получите массив из кучи инпутов и они составят одну строку, по этому нужно указать что 'mas[0]' И SwaD правильно написал уберите []

Оформите более красиво, с примером кода. Дублировать точь в точь комментарий не стоит
